# How to create a function where it assigns a number to entered information

Tags: c, function

This is in C.

Im trying to create a function where you enter basic information and it assigns you an account number that can be used throughout.

When running the program it always out puts the same number. I dont need it to store outside of the program but the function and program are supposed to be run multiple times. I need this portion of the code to work because there is a later part where I have to delete the information entered and the way I thought best would be to assign the information to a value like account number and then use that to delete everything.

Sample output: Welcome Test Test to Global Bank. Your account number is 0 your initial balance in your checking is 100 and your initial balance in your savings is 1000.

What im trying to accomplish is have the account number in the sample output be 1 then when I run the NewAccount function again it should output:

Welcome Test2 Test2 to Global Bank. Your account number is 2 your initial balance in your checking is 100 and your initial balance in your savings is 1000.

This is the code. I have tried giving customers, of struct Bank a value of 20 (`customers[20]`) but that didnt seem to help. This is where im stuck at.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Customer
{
char FirstName[100];
char LastName[100];
int CheckingBalance;
int SavingsBalance;
int MoneyMarketBalance;
unsigned AccountNumber;
};

struct Customer NewCustomer(void)
{

  static unsigned TopAccountNumber = 0;
  
  struct Customer customer;
  
  char FirstName[100];
  char LastName[100];
  int CheckingBalance;
  int SavingsBalance;
  int MoneyMarketBalance;
  unsigned AccountNumber;
  TopAccountNumber++;
  customer.AccountNumber = TopAccountNumber;
  return customer;
}

void NewAccount()
{
struct Customer customer;
printf("\nFirst name\n");
scanf("%s", customer.FirstName);
printf("\nLast name\n");
scanf("%s", customer.LastName);
printf("\nChecking deposit\n");
scanf("%d", &customer.CheckingBalance);
printf("\nSavings deposit\n");
scanf("%d", &customer.SavingsBalance); 
printf("\nWelcome %s %s to Global Bank. Your account number is %d your initial balance in your checking is %d and your initial balance in your savings is %d.", customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, customer.AccountNumber, customer.CheckingBalance, customer.SavingsBalance);
}

int main()
{
int choice;
printf("\n1 is the problem function. After you enter your inital values run 1 again and run a second set of values \n to exit press '7'.\n"); 
while(1){
scanf("%d", &choice);
switch(choice)
{
case 1:
NewAccount();
break;
case 7:
printf("Have a good day and thank you for banking with Global Bank!\n");
exit(0);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Weird. I seem to have recenly closed a question with very similar code fragment, which e.g. also ended right in the middle of a function. Did you ask one like this and got it deleted maybe? Just in case, please understand that deleting questions and reasking them will burden your account and you will have a harder time to recover. Consider deleting this and working on the older copy.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  `customers` is a single variable but you presumably want an array of them.  Add an account number to your `struct Bank` and then either keep them in order so the next account is the last + 1, or iterate through customers and use max + 1.  You probably do not want to use the array index, btw, as deleting an account means you now have a permanent empty slot.

Comment: You say the program (I assume you mean one which contains the shown code, because the shown code does not have a `main()` and hence cannot be run.) runs and outputs something. I doubt that, because the shown code (even if augmented with enough basic code...) does not look like it can be compiled without errors. Please show a [mre] of the code which does compile without errors and behaves as you describe.

Comment: "I have tried giving customers, of struct Bank a value of 20 (customers[20]) " As was pointed out that actually seems a good idea. Please show a [mre] of that attempt. What are the symptoms of "that didnt seem to help" with that attempt?

Comment: @AllanWind what would recommend instead of an array? Im assuming a hash would probably be better

Comment: Thanks for showing the `main()` function. The shown code is however implausible, because `main()` is inside another function and you have many syntax-breaking `\\` characters in your code. Please provide a [mre] (follow the link and read please) of a program which acts as you describe and demonstrates the problems with your array-using attempt.

Comment: An array is a fine choice for a container.  If you have a linked list or hash table around that is fine too, but your hash table usually doesn't support iteration (display of all accounts).

Comment: @Yunnosch What happened when giving customers a value of 20 I was unable to figure out a way to get the value to increase so when I would do that it would always print whatever I would set I to.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the MRE ([mre]) and the description of the symptoms. I bet that the shown code is not the one which you managed to compile and run.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes because I do not want to copy and paste my entire block of code. If it helps you then I can but Im trying to keep any unnecessary printfs and other negligible statements out of the post

Comment: You use the phrase "copy and paste my entire block of code", which causes me to think that you neither understood (maybe not even read) the concept of a MRE, nor the fact that even the shown fragment of code causes compiler errors on syntax level (actually even lower, on the allowed character set...). The solution to both problems is to get and apply the idea of an MRE.

Comment: In other words: please click on the link and read it carefully!

Comment: Your recent edit shows that there is the interface for a `NewCustomer()` function, which returns a customer struct. The customer struct contains a variable `AccountNumber`. That makes me think that setting the account number is not meant to be done inside `NewAccount`. Actually I think having `AccountNumber` as a single variable inside customer struct is a mistake. I expect a `CustomerNumber` inside the customer struct and `AccountNumber` inside account struct. And something to link both kinds of structs, e.g. `CustomerNumber` within account struct. Please review the design with your fellows.

Comment: @Yunnosch I just made the edits the other person in the thread helped me with. I have updated the code it runs now and demonstrates the problem with the function in case 1.

Answer (score 0):

A "bank" *have* customers, but isn't a customer in itself. So the `Bank` structure is rather badly named. And if one customer can only have a single account-number, then make it a part of the "customer" structure as well.

As for giving each customer a unique account number, one simple way is to keep track of the current highest number using a variable. Then when you create a new customer you increase that variable by one, and assign it to the customers specific account number.

For example:

```
struct Customer
{
    // Other customer data...
    unsigned AccountNumber;
};

struct Customer NewCustomer(void)
{
    // This is the base for all account numbers
    static unsigned TopAccountNumber = 0;

    struct Customer customer;

    // Initialize other customer data...

    ++TopAccountNumber;  // Increase top account number

    customer.AccountNumber = TopAccountNumber;

    return customer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your point about the bank thing makes sense I will be attempting to implement these thing and will respond if a problem comes up

Comment: You may disagree but I think we should discourage global variables.

Comment: @AllanWind hopefully the global variable thing isnt a super big deal because Im going to be making this into a .c file to be implement into a larger .c file (This is a group project)

Comment: If you say "implement into a larger .c file", please confirm that you know that *including* .c files into other files is not a good idea. The project/make file (whatever your class is using) should allow to use multiple .c files for your project. @TZZR-Gaming

Comment: @AllanWind No I don't really disagree, so I changed it. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Im sure im doing something wrong with placement but I have updated the code in the post to represent where I am now. Im still getting the same issue as the function keeps saying the account number is 0

Comment: @TZZR-Gaming You need to merge `NewCustomer` and `NewAccount`. Do the account-number initialization from `NewCustomer`, and the other customer initialization in `NewAccount`. Return the customer structure from the merged function. And remember to actually *call* it.